# Excel date format to Python date

Tags: python, excel, datetime, python-datetime

My data looks like this

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 40179 | 7.65 |
| 10210 | 6.87 |

I want to change the Date to a YYYY-MM-DD format.

It should look like this:

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 7.65 |
| 2010-02-01 | 6.87 |

Comment: Are you sure about those values? 10210 is less than 40179 yet the corresponding date is later. Perhaps it should be 40210

Comment: what is the criteria for mapping ts to date? Im confused

Comment: You need to bear in mind that Microsoft Excel uses the bizarre Epoch of 01-01-1900

Answer (score 0):

Using @DarkKnight's comment, this would transform your dates:

```py
import datetime

epoch = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('1900-01-01')

# for every day value, here 40177
newday = epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=40177)
isostring = newday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(isostring) # 2010-01-01
```